# Фрагмент на весь экран

Tags: android, java

Как можно сделать, чтобы фрагмент выходил на весь экран?

Дело в том, что когда делаю replace фрагмента, она выходит не на весь экран, а только по контенту, и виден другой фрагмент, хотя в xml написано `match_parent` и высота, и ширина. В чем здесь дело?

Comment: Если Фрагмент был определён в разметке через xml, то его нельзя убрать (и через replace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, у второго фрагмента, который замещает первый, у корневого элемента в xml `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` (это свойство всегда по умолчанию, если не переопределить тему приложения и не назначить в ней).